# rust libc::setsockopt cast to c_void

Tags: rust, libc, setsockopt

I'm trying to call [`setsockopt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.8.0/libc/fn.setsockopt.html) but can't figure out the cast to `c_void`.  `IP_HDRINCL` isn't in `nix` or `socket` crates, so I have to use `libc`.  I'm following the example of [How to set the socket option SO_REUSEPORT in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468685/how-to-set-the-socket-option-so-reuseport-in-rust)

```
let trueval: c_int = 1;
let ret = setsockopt(mysocket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &trueval as *const _ as *const c_void, mem::size_of_val(&trueval) as socklen_t);
```

```
error: expected expression, found keyword `const`
  --> src/igmp.rs:30:97
   |
30 |         let ret = setsockopt(mysocket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &trueval as *const _ *const c_void, mem::size_of_val(&trueval) as socklen_t);
   |                                                                                      ^^^^^ expected expression
```

Comment: *cast to c_void* — this doesn't make any sense. `void` is a type that cannot exist; you cannot cast to it.

Comment: You didn't read the linked SO question/answer then.  You can, and once my trueval type changes to a `u8` it works.

Comment: *You didn't read the linked SO question/answer then* — I **wrote** the linked answer. You cannot cast a value to a `void`.

Comment: Then why does changing the c_int type to u8 make it work, with the cast from the linked answer?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. [Running your code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=0fedb7d7e7c9b7447f483ee62f651a78) produces errors that are different from what you report. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: Your problem is simply a typo.  The code you provided says `&trueval as *const _ as *const c_void` but the error message says `&trueval as *const _ *const c_void`. You forgot the second **`as`** in whatever code you attempted first. The cast works just fine.

Comment: My point about `void` is that you aren't casting a value to void, you are casting a value to a pointer to void (`*const c_void` (Rust) / `void *` (C)). These have very  different meanings.

Answer (score -2):

Changing `trueval` to type `u8` allows the code to work.